# Google Sheets Fill Down with Formula

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have a very hard problem to solve, which must be completed with a formula (not a script).
Basically, the Raw input column needs to be dynamically filled down until it hits the next piece of text.

Here's an example file with includes the expected output.
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1ibqCvY39NlhCRWsbBdxKITUUpVpp9wXdEz44T-pHDY0/

Is it even possible to achieve?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Delete everything in Column B (including the header) and place the following formula in B1:

`=ArrayFormula({"Header";VLOOKUP(FILTER(ROW(A2:A),ROW(A2:A)<=MAX(FILTER(ROW(A2:A),A2:A<>""))),FILTER({ROW(A2:A),A2:A},A2:A<>""),2,TRUE)})`

Here is a basic explanation of how this formula works:

A virtual array is created between the curly brackets { }; this virtual array contains a header and all results. You can change the header name to whatever you like.

`VLOOKUP` looks up every row number that is less than or equal to the highest row number that contains text in A2:A. Each of these qualifying rows is looked up in a second array that contains only the row numbers and Column-A data from non-blank rows, returning the data itself. Since rows are in perfect ascending order and the last parameter of `VLOOKUP` is set to `TRUE`, all blank rows in the  first array will "fall backward" to find the most recent row that did have something in Column A.

Comment: Jesus, that's awesome! Congratulations, you rock!

Comment: Glad it is what you wanted. Thanks for completing the circle by marking the answer as "Best Answer."

Comment: Many more functions have been released since this post date. Today, for ease of use, I'd go with `=ArrayFormula(LET(header, "Solution", raw, A2:A, rr, ROW(raw), {header; VLOOKUP(FILTER(rr, rr <=MAX(FILTER(rr, raw<>""))), FILTER({rr, raw}, raw<>""), 2, TRUE)}))`  -or-  `=ArrayFormula(LET(raw, A2:A, header, "Solution", max_row, MAX(ROW(raw) * (raw<>"")), {header; IF(ROW(raw) > max_row,, SCAN(, raw, LAMBDA(i, a, IF(a = "", i, a))))}))`

Answer (score 1):

This will work based on your ask, assuming that A2 is never blank, place this in the first row of data (not header):

```
=ArrayFormula(IF(A2:A<>"", A2:A, B1:B))
```

It checks to see if there is a value in column A, if there is, it fills that column, if not, it copies the cell above.