# Arrayformula for text based on another column's entries until another row h

Tags: google-sheets, header

I'm trying to autofill a column with text based off of certain Row headers

Example: Column B is the array formula, filling in various Headers from Column A. Column C is a way to determine if the text in Column A is a header. So if C="" it's a header

| Column A | Column B | Column C | Column D |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Header 1 |  |  | sum of rows with Header 1 |
| text | Header 1 | has text | # |
| text | Header 1 | has text | # |
| Header 2 |  |  | sum of rows with Header 2 |
| text | Header 2 | has text | # |
| text | Header 2 | has text | # |

I've been trying to adapt formulas I found on another question/answer:
[Google Sheets Fill Down with Formula](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66859631/google-sheets-fill-down-with-formula/77792721#77792721)

But I couldn't understand the formulas well enough to fit in a criteria to only select rows where C = ""

I'd greatly appreciate any advice on how to adjust one of those formulas! Or if you know of a better formula to work with

The reason I want a formula like this is because I have multiple columns that add together sub-totals for all rows that have this Header, for each header. And the rows are constantly being added to or subtracted or even moved to different Headers

I tried adding in an AND criteria to where I thought the formula was filtering down to only non-blank A cells (**BOLD** was my best guess at what to adjust, although I tried many things)

=ArrayFormula({"Header";VLOOKUP(FILTER( ROW(A2:A),ROW(A2:A)<=MAX(FILTER(ROW(A7:A),**and(A2:A<>"",C2:C="")**))),FILTER({ROW(A2:A),A7:A},**and(A2:A<>"",C2:C="")**),2,TRUE)})

Same with this formula, but I honestly barely understand this one:

=ArrayFormula(LET(raw, A7:A, header, "Solution", max_row, MAX(ROW(raw) * (raw<>"") * **(C2:C="")**), {header; IF(ROW(raw) > max_row,, SCAN(, raw, LAMBDA(i, a, IF(a = "", i, a))))}))

Comment: please share a sample sheet with example of your data and desired result. You can [Make an anonymous sample document](https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLScf4e8rJpjbDx-SQOH2c2xIaUP-ewnNJoqv9uRAXIrenUvZ_Q/viewform)